# operating numcolwise on a specified columns

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I am working with a large cross country panel data. Here is a sample of my data:

```
df <- structure(list(country = c("Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", 
"Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", 
"Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", 
"Argentina", "Argentina", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", 
"Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", 
"Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil"), year = c(1991, 1992, 
1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 
2004, 2005, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 
2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005), lnunderval = c(-0.942018220566855, 
-0.885848248127534, -0.766349222095516, -0.690487190951407, -0.521023028925771, 
-0.288557433912095, -0.351488637772915, -0.393048184068511, -0.444123691025518, 
-0.512425182981147, -0.541182815398097, 0.379018666505875, 0.291852440172936, 
0.291407056285245, 0.221426753100227, -0.120418577004832, 0.00467960055625634, 
-0.0190735963658737, -0.239570582118898, -0.316748349307701, 
-0.205418347557874, -0.301707274202926, -0.346946676711871, -0.0528811487098006, 
-0.178001370772517, -0.0404491572081528, 0.0898307782259906, 
0.0835291098039626, 0.0349739055576117, -0.187321483795299), 
    manu_GDP = c(24.3864490932335, 21.8591315586603, 18.2399115325496, 
    17.8190917106899, 17.2467521148076, 17.5357232920479, 18.227905749866, 
    17.8379584760908, 16.9615250614589, 16.4942719439838, 16.0932258763829, 
    20.347773913878, 22.4867505875749, 18.9370136214371, 18.340415936715, 
    21.8391379495813, 23.3085986320751, 26.0497364463813, 23.7212337008806, 
    14.5422791544751, 13.0671912367218, 13.0186253732125, 12.1551371940101, 
    12.3085333305115, 13.134659593552, 13.0895379354001, 12.3569626673735, 
    14.4507645630532, 15.0995301563871, 14.7382811342998), income = c("Upper middle income", 
    "Upper middle income", "Upper middle income", "Upper middle income", 
    "Upper middle income", "Upper middle income", "Upper middle income", 
    "Upper middle income", "Upper middle income", "Upper middle income", 
    "Upper middle income", "Upper middle income", "Upper middle income", 
    "Upper middle income", "Upper middle income", "Upper middle income", 
    "Upper middle income", "Upper middle income", "Upper middle income", 
    "Upper middle income", "Upper middle income", "Upper middle income", 
    "Upper middle income", "Upper middle income", "Upper middle income", 
    "Upper middle income", "Upper middle income", "Upper middle income", 
    "Upper middle income", "Upper middle income"), period = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("(1990,1995]", 
    "(1995,2000]", "(2000,2005]"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I created five-year non-overlapping averages of my variables using cut and ddply functions as below.

```
df$period <- cut(df$year, seq(1990, 2005, 5)) #this periodizes data
df <- ddply(df, .(country, period), numcolwise(mean))
```

The problem with this code is that the non-numeric column named income is lost. I've tried the following but it did not work.

```
df <- ddply(df, .(country, period), numcolwise(mean,.(lnunderval, manu_GDP))) 
Error in mean.default(X[[i]], ...) : 'trim' must be numeric of length one
```

I would like to final dataset to contain non-numeric columns that are not averaged. Is there a way of applying the numcolwise function on a specified set of columns?

I would like the final output to look like this:

```
structure(list(country = c("Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", 
"Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil"), period = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("(1990,1995]", "(1995,2000]", "(2000,2005]"
), class = "factor"), year = c(1993, 1998, 2003, 1993, 1998, 
2003), lnunderval = c(-0.761145182133417, -0.397928625952037, 
0.128504420133237, -0.13822630084821, -0.216990963590998, -0.00388736948317731
), manu_GDP = c(19.9102672019882, 17.4114769046895, 19.2410359871976, 
21.8921971766787, 12.7368293456016, 13.9470152913027), income = c("Upper middle income", 
"Upper middle income", "Upper middle income", "Upper middle income", 
"Upper middle income", "Upper middle income")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: You are summarising the data, perhaps you need to summarise and join with the original data, or keep the `income` also in the grouping variable

Comment: Or may use `dplyr`, which is more flexible `df %>% group_by(country, period) %>% summarise(income = unique(income), across(c(lnunderval, manu_GDP), mean), .groups = 'drop')`

Comment: The second comment gets me close to what I need but it generates duplicate rows when applied to my complete dataset.

Comment: It is because you may have more than one unique income per each group of country, period.  Usually `summarise` returns a single row per group because mean returns a single value.  You could wrap as a list column ie.. `income = list(unique(income)),.`

Comment: If you can show your expected output based on the input you showed, it would be helpful

Comment: I've edited the question to show my expected output. income = list(unique(income)) again gets me closer to my expected output except that missing values in the income column complicate the output. I tried income = list(unique(income, na.rm=TRUE)) but that does not seem to help. Some cells appear like this: c(NA, "Upper middle income")

Comment: `unique` doesn't have `na.rm` argument.  You need `list(unique(income[complete.cases(income)]))`

Comment: For me, this works `df %>% group_by(country, period) %>% summarise(year = last(year), income = list(unique(income[!is.na(income)])), across(c(lnunderval, manu_GDP), mean), .groups = 'drop')`  Based on your example, you don't need the `list` here though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `dplyr` which is more flexible with `across` to `summarise` multiple blocks of columns with different functions

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(country, period) %>%
  summarise(year = last(year), income = list(unique(income[!is.na(income)])), 
    across(c(lnunderval, manu_GDP), mean), .groups = 'drop')
```